# MySQL ORDER BY CASE + operator

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, case

I am trying to do a search that would be sorted by relevance. 
Let's say the search term contains 3 words: A, B and C. What I am trying to do is to check if the search term is present in the SELECT result and if yes that would increase its rank.

```
ORDER BY CASE
(
WHEN search_word_A_is_present THEN +1
WHEN search_word_B_is_present THEN +1
WHEN search_word_C_is_present THEN +1
ELSE 0
END
) 
DESC
```

While there is no syntax error and the search runs and sorts by something (that seems different from what I want) but I am not sure what is being added up if anything. How would I go about seeing what the final rank (sum) is at the end for each result? Is this the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since in MySQL boolean conditions result in `1` and `0`, you can simply add those up

```
ORDER BY search_word_A_is_present + search_word_B_is_present + search_word_C_is_present 
DESC
```

A more practical example:

```
ORDER BY col1 = 1 + col2 = 'A' + col3 = 44 DESC
```